# A matrix defines a self adjoint operator if and only if it is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know this is probably a silly question, but I'm stuck with it.

> $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $A$ real matrix ($n\times n$), then $\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,Ay\rangle \iff A^{T}=A$

I've tried to prove it using coordinates, but somehow I haven't managed to get the result. Also, I'm sure there must be a shorter way to prove this result.

Comment: What do you mean by "prove it using coordinates"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom using a basis. However, I don't understand why the expression $(A e_i = \Sigma a_{ij} e_j)$ holds.

Comment: That's just the definition of matrix multiplication at work

Comment: @V.González That is the definition of a matrix representing a linear operator. A linear operator is determined by where it sends basis vectors - that the expression on the left hand side. The right hand side is witness to the fact that any vector can be expressed as a linear combination of basis vectors. Now the point of a matrix is that if you plug in $(1, 0,\ldots,0)$ you get the first column - the $a_{1j}$... this is how a matrix encodes a linear operator.

Comment: @AreaMan but that just holds if A is symmetric. In general, it would be $a_{ji}$ instead of  $a_{ij}$.

Comment: @V.González I can never keep the order convention straight. But the point of $\Sigma a_{ij} e_j$ - you think of this as the image of $Ae_i$, so the $i$ is fixed because it is tagging the vector we are trying to describing with a basis, and then the j vary over the coefficients of the $e_j$. The crucial thing is that the $j$ is varying - sorry, it is a convention that repeated indices vary, maybe that wasn't clear. I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: What is $<A e_i, e_j>$? What is $<e_i, Ae_j>$? (Recalling that the definition of $A$ is $(a_{ij})$ with the property that $A e_i = \Sigma_{j = 1}^{n} a_{ij} e_j$ (or whatever order you put the indices in)).

Comment: This is only one direction of implication

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Pretty sure it gives both. The extra thing to check is that a bilinear map is determined by what it does to a pair of basis ($e_i \otimes e_j$ are the elements of a basis for $R^n \otimes R^n$). OP: This just means that to check that $<Ax,y> = <x,Ay>$ from knowing it for $x$ and $y$ just basis vectors, try to use the linearity properties of the inner product.

Comment: oh, I see. Interesting perspective.

Comment: @AreaMan So that gives me that if the equality holds, I know how to prove the symmetry. Any clue for the reverse statement?

Comment: @V.González The reverse statement is essentially in my reply to Omnomnomnom. The third sentence there is meant for you. Let me know if you want more details, but give it a go.

Comment: @AreaMan oh yeah! We could actually say that it is almost and "if and only if". Since dot product is bilinear, we just need to know what happens to a basis. And that equality holds if and ony if $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: @V.González Exactly. :) (The only pedantic quibble of wording, which I think you understand anyway, is that to know a bilinear map you need to know what happens to a pair of basis, one in each slot (which could be the same basis twice)... making this precise can lead you to the notion of tensor products, which builds a new vector space on which the behavior of a blinear map - for example <A_, _> - is recorded as a linear map...)

Answer (score 2):

Note $\langle Ax,y\rangle=(Ax)^Ty=x^TA^Ty$ and $\langle x,Ay\rangle=x^TAy$. The result follows from these two observations.

Comment: That is only one direction of implication

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Both follows from here, the other implication should follow from the fact that $Mx=0$ for all $x$ implies $M=0$, I left this as exercise.

Comment: Okay, so you left the other direction as an exercise